Does 2D Ising model has a spin-wave gap?
I was confused by two statements which are contradicting while learning about magnetism in 2D systems.

2D Ising model has phase transition and long-range magnetic order.
2D Ising model does not have a spin-wave gap.

From my understanding, the spin fluctuation in dimensions lower than 3 destroys long-range order (LRO), unless there is a spin-wave gap. How can 2D Ising model has a LRO without a spin-wave gap? According to the study: Direct measurement of 2D magnon in CrI3, where CrI3 is considered as a realization of 2D Ising model, there is a spin-wave gap of 0.3 meV. Therefore, is the second statement false?

Maybe you are getting confused between the ising mode (discrete 1 and -1 spin) and the xy model (continuous vector spin on a 2d plane). The ising model is gapped because the minimal energy change is finite while the xy model is not because you can rotate a little bit a spin to change its energy by a vanishing amount. The ising model in 2d does have long range order while the xy model does not.

Hi Syrocco, I do appreciate your answer. I am sure I am always discussing the Ising case where the spins can only pointing along the z axis. Do you have any reference specifically states that the 2D Ising model is gapped? Thank you

I did not see your quantum-mechanics tag, I thought you were talking about classical stuff. Unfortunately I don't know a thing about quantum mechanics. In classical physics at least, there is no need for a source, there cannot even exist a "wave" again because the minimal non zero energy change due to a spin flip is something proportional to an integer times the coupling constant. Because the states are discrete. Hence it is gapped almost by definition. But this is the classical picture of what we call an ising model. In quantum stuff, I don't know

Here, I assume you mean the transverse-field Ising model
\begin{align}
H_\text{Ising} = J \sum _{j = 1}^L S^z_j S^z_{j+1} + h \sum _{j = 1}^L S^x_j
\end{align}
where $J < 0$ and thus the model is ferromagnetic. (From your question it is not clear whether you are talking about a temperature driven or quantum phase transition, which is why I will not go into this direction. That is why I will only consider the case $h = 0$). Furthermore, I assume a bipartite lattice throughout, such that spin on the sublattice $A$ only interact with the ones on sublattice $B$, i.e. a chain, a square lattice, a simple cubic lattice, ... . (If you go to frustrated lattices and antiferromagntic couplings, you will get more exotic physics, namely spin ices, but I will not touch upon them).


2D Ising model has phase transition and long-range magnetic order.


As mentioned above, I will not go into the phase transition. Without a transversal field, $h = 0$, the degenerate groundstate of the model are the fully magnetized states
\begin{align}
| F^\uparrow \rangle = | \uparrow \uparrow \cdots \uparrow \rangle, \qquad
| F^\downarrow \rangle = | \downarrow \downarrow \cdots \downarrow \rangle
.
\end{align}
These two states have the same energy but are macroscopically distinct, such that in a real physical system with small external field one of the states is spontaneously chosen, let's say $| F^\uparrow \rangle$ was chosen. Then, computing the long-range order (LRO) of this state,
\begin{align}
\langle F^\uparrow | S^z_i S^z _j | F^\uparrow \rangle = \frac{1}{4}
,
\end{align}
we find that it indeed has LRO in any dimension. This is also true for the antiferromagnetic case under the assumption that we have a bipartite lattice.


2D Ising model does not have a spin-wave gap.


If you mean with "spin-wave gap" the energy gap to create the lowest spin-wave (on top of the groundstate with energy $E_0$) then this is false. For the sake of simplicity I again assume $h = 0$. We can simply create a spin flip excitation
\begin{align}
| F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l \rangle := S^- _l | F^\uparrow \rangle = | \uparrow \uparrow \cdots \uparrow \downarrow _l \uparrow \cdots \uparrow \rangle
,
\end{align}
and find that its an eigenstate of $H_\text{Ising}$ (its a classical Hamiltonian) and its energy cost is finite
\begin{align}
H_\text{Ising} | F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l \rangle = (E_0 + 2J) | F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l \rangle , \qquad
\langle F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l | (H_\text{Ising} - E_0) | F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l \rangle = 2J
.
\end{align}
We can then straightforwardly construct the spin waves as
\begin{align}
| k \rangle := \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \sum _{l=1}^L e^{-i k l}| F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l \rangle
,
\end{align}
which obviously are eigenstates of $H_\text{Ising}$ because the $| F^\uparrow, \downarrow _l \rangle$ already are. The spin waves have no dispersion relation and their energy is simply
\begin{align}
\langle k | (H_\text{Ising} - E_0) | k \rangle = 2J
.
\end{align}
This shows that the spin wave gap is finite and thus $H_\text{Ising}$ does have a spin-wave gap.

From my understanding, the spin fluctuation in dimensions lower than 3 destroys long-range order (LRO), unless there is a spin-wave gap.

I have to admit I am not aware of this theorem. (Possibly you mean the Mermin-Wagner-Hohenberg theorem?). But because the Ising model does not have [quantum] spin fluctuations and clearly shows LRO in multiple dimensions (assuming bipartite lattices), I will choose as a counter example a different (quantum) spin model. The antiferromagentic, $J > 0$, Heisenberg model $H_\text{Heis} = J \sum _{j} \vec{S}_j \cdot \vec{S}_{j+1}$ on a 2D square lattice displays LRO, spontaneous symmetry breaking and has gapless excitations (i.e. the spin wave gap is zero). This is in contradiction to the statement you wrote.
I hope I have given you some insight into the underlying physics and adressed some of your main points.

Hi Mark, thanks for the great answer and explaining things so thoroughly! It indeed answered many of my questions. To make sure I understand you correctly: 1.The energy cost 2J of a single spin flip is coming from that particular spin and its left/right neighbors, and subtracted the ground state energy, correct?  2. Yes, I was referring to the Mermin-Wagner theorem at the end. 2.You claim in Ising model there is no quantum fluctuation, that's because there is only Sz involved, but if we introduce a trasverse Zeeman term hSx, then there will be quantum fluctuation because [Sx, Sz]==0, correct?

(1) Yes, that is correct. (2) I just want to add that the Mermin-Wagner-Hohenberg theorem would not apply to the transverse field Ising model, because there is no continuous symmetry (in contrast to the Heisenberg model). (3) Exactly, and a transversal field will then lead to spin-flip dynamics because the terms dont commute. (In the purely Ising model, the spin waves have no dispersion and thus a velocity of zero. In other words a spin flip will not create excitations/spin waves that spread within the system).

Thank you Mark!!
